# Недавно стал изучать ботов на питоне. В телеграм боте после создания одной функции, неработает следующая

Tags: python, функции, telebot

Скину не весь код, так как он слишком большой

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['admin_ban'], content_types=['text'])
def admin_block(message):
    if password in message.text:
        message.text = message.text.replace('/admin_ban', '')
        message.text = message.text.replace(password, '')
        message.text = message.text.replace(' ', '')
        b_users.append(message.text)
        bl = open('ban_list.txt', 'w')
        bl.write(str(b_users))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'В бан закинут @{message.text}')
        bl.close()
    else:
        admin(message)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def command(message):

    now = datetime.now() 
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M") 
    user_id_text = "@" + str(message.from_user.username), str(message.text), str(time),'\n'
    bl = open('ban_list.txt', 'r')
    bl.read()

    for i in bl:
        t = 0
        if message.from_user.username in bl:
            t += 1
        if t == 0:
            if time >= '06.00.00' and time < '19.00.00':   
                
                u_dont = """
                ты не любишь:("""
                
                black_list = """
                ты используешь слова/символы, которые находятся в черном списке"""
                
                m = [i for i in message.text]
                if len(m) < 250:
                    if 'я люблю' in message.text or 'Я люблю' in message.text:
                            
                        message.text = message.text.replace('я люблю', '')
                        message.text = message.text.replace('Я люблю', '')
                            
                        if message.text == '' or message.text == ' ':
                                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, u_dont)
                                
                        else:
                                
                            t=0
                            for x in b_list:
                                    
                                if x in message.text:
                                    t += 1
                                else:
                                    t += 0
                                        
                            if t > 0:
                                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, black_list)
                                    
                            else:
                                post = f"""
                                Запосщенно - {id_channel}
                                """
                                bot.send_message(id_channel, message.text)
                                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, post)
                                users.append(user_id_text)
                                f = open('i_love.txt', 'w')
                                f.write(str(users))
                                f.close()
                    else:
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, u_dont)
                else:
                    too_far_text = """
                    текст слишком длинный, ты что, пытаешься сломать бота??"""
                    
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, too_far_text)
            else:
                
                not_time = """
                неподходящее время\nпопробуй позже :)\n \nну блин чел... было написано с 6 до 19 писать..."""
                
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, not_time)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы находитесь в бане.')
    bl.close()
```

Comment: и так уже пытался менять местами, ни ошибок не дает, ни хендлеры не работают

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался, в хендлере admin_ban можно было просто убрать content_types, все заработало